# Is there a way of making items in an arraylist into individual buttons?

Tags: codenameone

As seen in the image, I have a list generated using an ArrayList. I want to make each item (for example the highlighted) a button to another page. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that e.g. by looping the list and creating buttons which you can add to a container etc.

But you might be looking for button lists as covered here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/button-lists.html